# Extracting information from go-github Gist type

Tags: github, go, github-api

I have started learning Go and I find it quite interesting so far. As an assignment for myself to get get better at the language, I decided to write a Gister in Go using [go-github](https://github.com/google/go-github).

I have been able to get all my Gists using an access token and I am able to print as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/google/go-github/github"
import "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"

func main() {
    t := &oauth.Transport{
        Token: &oauth.Token{AccessToken: "secretaccesstokenhere"},
    }

    client := github.NewClient(t.Client())

    gists, _, err := client.Gists.List("", nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        for _, g := range gists {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", g.Files)
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
map[TODO.md:github.GistFile{Size:166, Filename:"TODO.md", RawURL:"somerawurlhere"}]

map[fourcore.c:github.GistFile{Size:309, Filename:"fourcore.c", RawURL:"somerawurlhere"}]

map[coretest.cpp:github.GistFile{Size:160, Filename:"coretest.cpp", RawURL:"somerawurlhere"}]
```

What I would like to print is "ID / FILENAME". I understand that I need to extract the ID from Gist type and Filename from above map but I wasn't able to find a way to do that. How do I do that? Help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: [Here](http://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-github/github#Gist) is the documentation describing Gist type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Files map, where filename is stored in key variable of type GistFilename, and ID is in Gist type variable. So you have to have two range's - one for Gists, other for Files.
Something like this:

```
    for _, g := range gists {
        for filename, _ := range g.Files {
            fmt.Printf("%v / %v\n", *g.ID, filename)
        }
    }
```

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
)

func main() {
    t := &oauth.Transport{
        Token: &oauth.Token{AccessToken: "secretaccesstokenhere"},
    }

    client := github.NewClient(t.Client())

    gists, _, err := client.Gists.List("", nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, g := range gists {
        for filename, _ := range g.Files {
            fmt.Printf("%v / %v\n", *g.ID, filename)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more question: The ID that is being printed is not the same that I see when I print `gists`. It prints something this: `0xc20813af60` instead of `910349555dc0175ab949`. How do I get it in the format that I like?

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad - ID is of type \*string (pointer to string), so 0xc20813af60 is a correct value of this type (address in memory). So we need to get value at that address, using asterisk (*):  fmt.Printf("%v / %v\n", *g.ID, filename)

I've modified code above with this change.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for answering quickly. This solves a lot of things for me.